# SQL Transpose? Need to display qty and price in one row, is this possible in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a system that stores tier prices for products in a separate table.  Now I am required to list all the products with their tier prices on a single row.  My tier price table looks like this:

```
ProductId   Quantity    Price
----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
12019       1           152.0208
12019       3           145.9375
12019       7           139.8542
12019       11          133.7710
12019       26          121.6044
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
ProductId   Qty1    Price1    Qty2  Price2    Qty3  Price3    ... Qty7  Price7
12019            1  152.0208  3 145.9375  7 139.8542
```

- We go up to 7 prices, but not all products have them, some may have 4 or 6.

Any advice you can provide will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks to Gordon for formatting correctly!

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I searched the forums and got that link from another post but the example is very basic and for one column.  I need to pivot on two columns and have no clue!

Comment: Yes the number of rows varies.  But the max is 7 pairs (Qty Price)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to figure it out somehow, maybe not the most elegant solution but it works!

I'm posting my solution in case someone wants an alternative to Pivot, which by the way, I think it's much easier to do by adding the row count field, see below

First I added a row count to the query and had it reset on change of my Id field:

```
select ProductId, 
ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY ProductId) AS Row,

Quantity, Price from TierPriceTable
```

I then simply wrote one query for each pair within each group:

```
select t.ProductID,
(select Qty from #prices where ProductID = t.ProductID and Row = 1) Qty1,
(select Price from #prices where ProductID = t.ProductID and Row = 1) Price1, 
(select Qty from #prices where ProductID = t.ProductID and Row = 2) Qty2,
(select Price from #prices where ProductID = t.ProductID and Row = 2) Price2, 
(select Qty from #prices where ProductID = t.ProductID and Row = 3) Qty3,
(select Price from #prices where ProductID = t.ProductID and Row = 3) Price3, 
(select Qty from #prices where ProductID = t.ProductID and Row = 4) Qty4,
(select Price from #prices where ProductID = t.ProductID and Row = 4) Price4, 
(select Qty from #prices where ProductID = t.ProductID and Row = 5) Qty5,
(select Price from #prices where ProductID = t.ProductID and Row = 5) Price5, 
(select Qty from #prices where ProductID = t.ProductID and Row = 6) Qty6,
(select Price from #prices where ProductID = t.ProductID and Row = 6) Price6,
(select Qty from #prices where ProductID = t.ProductID and Row = 7) Qty7,
(select Price from #prices where ProductID = t.ProductID and Row = 7) Price7 
from #prices t
group by t.ProductID
```

I used temp tables to make the queries simpler, but this is optional.

I hope this helps!